# how to rollback the transaction on customize aspect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

this is my code

```
@Around("service()")
public Object serviceThreadLocalHandle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    // joinPoint is a service instance
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    cache = ContractCache.LOCAL_CACHE.get();
    // there i throw a exception but i can not rollback the transaction
    if(true){
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return proceed;
}
```

so how can I rollback the transaction on my aspect spring boot version 1.5.8 RELEASE?

Comment: Where do you start the transaction?

Comment: You can surround your method with  @Transactional annotaion in spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare in the @Transactional annotation that you want to perform a rollback when your RuntimeException is thrown:
@Transactional(rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)